# Управление глагола в отрицании мн. ч.

Tags: управление

Здравствуйте, я только что в журнале прочитал предложение: "они не покидают своих домов". Но по -моему лучше звучит "не покидают свои дома". Который вариант правильный? Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существительное, относящееся к глаголу с отрицанием, может иметь форму родительного или винительного падежа. Однако есть случаи, при которых тот или иной падеж является предпочтительным.
**Винительный падеж необходим при наличии в предложении местоимений, указывающих на определенность объекта:**

***Эту*** песню не задушишь, не убьешь.
*Ростов, не желая навязывать **свое** знакомство, не пошел в дом* (Л. Толстой).
([**Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr))

Правильно будет использовать винительный падеж:
*Они не покидают **свои дома***(не покидают - что? - дома); *они не оставляют **свои дома**; они не бросают **свои дома.***

[Для сравнения. Если притяжательное местоимение "свой/свои" отсутствует, то возможны оба падежа: они не покидают домов/дома; они не бросают домов/дома.]

Answer (score 1):

> ...только что в журнале прочитал предложение: *"они не покидают своих
>   домов"*. Но, по-моему, лучше звучит *"не покидают свои дома"*. Который
>   вариант правильный?

Правильны оба варианта, но **ЧАЩЕ** употребляется первый: ***не покидают своих домов***.

Сравните сами:

[**"не покидают своих домов"**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%22&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=bks&biw=1280&bih=825)

[**"не покидают свои дома"**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%22&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=bks&biw=1280&bih=825)